# CREATE TRIGGER to monitor a specific table row

Tags: mysql, sql, informix

I have two tables & need to write a TRIGGER for this scenario.
1. **Parameters_Table(int pkid, string param_name, string param_value)**
2. **Tokens_Table(int pkid,string item,string validity)**
I have a requirement of deleting all entries in Tokens_Table if a particular row where param_name='Enterprise' in Parameters_Table changes its 'param_value'. The value is changed from UI. 
eg., row <7,enterprise,60> changes to <7,enterprise,25> in Parameters_Table then delete all entries from Tokens_Table.

How should I write the trigger. Please guide. (I need to write this for Informix Database, but mysql queries would also help)

Comment: You say `'Enterprise'` and then show `'enterprise'` — which case are you worried about?  Is it "when any row in the Parameters_Table with a param_name of 'enterprise' changes the parameter value, then every row must be deleted from Tokens_Table"; or is it only some token entries that need to be deleted?  What about an identity update (an UPDATE executes, but the param_value 'changes' from '60' to '60')?  Does it matter what the PKID in the Parameters_Table is?  Can there be more than one row with the same param_name value?

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_update AFTER UPDATE ON Parameters_Table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF OLD.param_name ='Enterprise' THEN
    IF NEW.param_value != OLD.param_value THEN
      DELETE FROM Tokens_Table WHERE pkid = NEW.pkid;
    END IF;
  END IF;
END$$
```

Just try above code.Hope this will helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following syntax/format:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER delete_tokens AFTER INSERT ON Parameters_Table
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF NEW.param_name = 'enterprise' THEN 
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Tokens_Table WHERE pkid = NEW.pkid;
    END; 
  END IF;
END$$
```

Comment: Have you made your duty?

Comment: On the face of it, the question is asking about UPDATE statements, not INSERT statements.  It might be rescuable if you added the UPDATE trigger too.